# How do I remove 'additional' unwanted columns from a Word table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Some of my Word doc tables have 4 columns, and some have more.  In any case, whenever I have more than 4 columns, I need to delete all columns beyond the 4th row.

(i.e. if I have 6 columns, I need to delete columns #5 & #6, leaving me with the first columns)

Can anyone offer a suggestion for a VBA macro that will remove all columns beyond the 4th column?

If Column #5, Delete Column #5, Loop.  How do I put this into VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Dim tbl As Table

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
''First column is 1, not 0, ditto rows.
    If tbl.Columns.Count > 4 Then
        For i = tbl.Columns.Count To 5 Step -1
            tbl.Columns(i).Delete
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Remou, that looks good.  I've run a small test at home and it looks good.  I'll run it at work tomorrow and we'll see how it goes...